# R - remove "one after another" duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, zoo

I try to find a way to remove succesive duplicates in R language. I have a `zoo` object like:

```
2015-01-01 12:00:00    1
2015-01-01 13:00:00    1
2015-01-01 14:00:00    1
2015-01-01 15:30:00    4
2015-01-01 16:00:00    1
2015-01-01 17:00:00    6
```

and my expected result is:

```
2015-01-01 12:00:00    1
2015-01-01 15:30:00    4
2015-01-01 16:00:00    1
2015-01-01 17:00:00    6
```

When I use the duplicated-function, it removes the duplicates (1) also when they don't come successively.

Can anyone give me a hint how to write this or if there is already a function available?

Comment: `data[sequence(rle(c(1,1,1,4,1,6))$lengths) == 1, ]` or `data[which(sequence(rle(c(1,1,1,4,1,6))$lengths) == 1), ]` might me safer

Comment: @rawr nice one. Just replace `c` with the column name and post as an answer. This is the comment sections here :). Thank you.

Comment: Btw, with `data.table` v >= 1.9.5 I would do `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[df[,  .I[1L], by = rleid(V2)]$V1]`. But this probably not necessary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the run length encoding lengths to pick out the rows you want. If used raw in a `cumsum` it will give you the *last* value in a sequence, but you can get the first by subtracting the lengths from the cumulative sum and adding one.

```
x <- data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()+0:5,Value=c(1,1,1,4,1,6))
lens <- rle(x$Value)$lengths
select <- cumsum(lens)-lens+1
x[select,]
        Date Value
1 2015-05-13     1
4 2015-05-16     4
5 2015-05-17     1
6 2015-05-18     6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr and lubridate, you can do it as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DF <- data.frame(Date=c("2015-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "2015-01-01 13:00:00","2015-01-01 15:30:00"),
                 name1=c(1, 1, 4))

DF %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(as.character(Date))) %>%
  filter(Date - hours(1) > lag(Date) | is.na(lag(Date)))
```

`dplyr` lets you refer to a row above (`lag`) and `lubridate` lets you calculate with dates.